# Recover all databases in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am using wamp server in my local and want to give super privilege to my mysql database and run this 
  query 
  **grant all privileges on DATABASE_NAME.* to root1@localhost identified by 'PASSWORD';**
  after that i cant run my phpmyadmin in local it shows this error 
  **#1045 - Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: NON)**

From begining i am use root as my username but i am type root1 here after that i am facing this issue.I am also trying to change username to root1 in 
 **wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/config.inc.php** after that phpmyadmin open but all databases vanished.If i put username as root in config.inc.php then it shows this below screen shot error.

[image]

Comment: You can restart with permission checking turned off to recover.

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after `GRANT`.

Comment: Means i have to restart mysql again or what? can you tadman tell me brifely

Comment: how to run FLUSH PRIVILEGES; right now no databases showing in phpmyadmin.

Comment: You can run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` in a regular SQL windows in phpMyAdmin. But are you sure you have not modified the password for the root user ?

Comment: No i am not modify password and username but after run this - grant all privileges on DATABASE_NAME.* to root1@localhost identified by 'PASSWORD'; my username root changed to root1 in inc file and all databases vanished.

Comment: if i change to root1 as username in config.inc file after that phpmyadmin open but no database showing